# jquery Show and hide menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to Jquery so forgive me for the simple question. I have a created a mulitple show and hide menu, which works fine, however i want to add an extra function to it. When click on for example the blackJack 1 slots it it opens the dropdown menu. when i click on it whilst open it close the menu also. Looking at my code does anyone know how this could be achieved?

At present the current works when you click on "slot" it opens the next slot and closes the previous slot.

### HTML

```
<div class="drop-inner slots">
    <h2>Blackjack</h2>
</div>

<div class="hide-me">
    <p>content goes here</p>
</div>


<div class="drop-inner slots">
    <h2>Blackjack 2</h2>
</div>

<div class="hide-me">
    <p>content goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="drop-inner slots">
    <h2>Blackjack 3</h2>
</div>

<div class="hide-me">
    <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$(function () {
     $('.slots').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.hide-me').slideUp().removeClass('active');
        $this.next('.hide-me').slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
     });
 });
```

Comment: Isn't his a basic accordion that you're after?

Comment: @j08691 yes if that is the correct term for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if the `$next` element is visible or not.

```
$('.slots').click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $next = $this.next('.hide-me');

    $('.hide-me').slideUp().removeClass('active');
    if ($next.css('display') !== 'none') {
        $next.slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $next.slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EjbLQ/)

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock Yes, me too. Don't forget to mark it if you consider the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick

```
$(function () {
    $('.hide-me').hide();
    $('.slots').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisHideMe = $this.next('.hide-me');
        $('.hide-me').not($thisHideMe).slideUp().removeClass('active');
        $thisHideMe.slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PjkuH/)

Answer (score 0):

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/nexk5/1/ :)

```
 $(function () {
     $('.slots').click(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         var $next_hideme = $this.next('.hide-me');
         $('.hide-me').not($next_hideme).slideUp().removeClass('active');
         if (!$next_hideme.hasClass('active')) {
             $next_hideme.slideDown('slow').addClass('active');
         } else {
             $next_hideme.slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
         }
         });
     });
```

Comment: in the rush of having your question answered first i didn't think of using `.slideToggle` and `.toggleClass`, the code above will still do the job perfectly, however for shorter code please look at Claudio Redi's answer :)